# is there any way to use socket.io-redis in nest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io, nestjs

i want to use them together.
after some search i find nest init socket io in
[io-adapter.ts](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/websockets/adapters/io-adapter.ts)

```
export class IoAdapter implements WebSocketAdapter {
  constructor(private readonly httpServer: Server | null = null) {}

  public create(
    port: number,
    options?: any & { namespace?: string; server?: any },
  ): any {
    if (!options) {
      return this.createIOServer(port);
    }
    const { namespace, server, ...opt } = options;
    return server && isFunction(server.of)
      ? server.of(namespace)
      : namespace
        ? this.createIOServer(port, opt).of(namespace)
        : this.createIOServer(port, opt);
  }
```

it seems to has not api to do that.
i also find some clues .

```
app.useWebSocketAdapter(/*some adapter*/);
```

maybe i should write a new ioadapter?
please give me some help. thanks